# How do I alter the comments form in several different ways?

Tags: comments

I already altered my comments form by replacing
`<?php comment_form(); ?>`
with
`<?php comment_form(array('title_reply'=>'Leave a comment')); ?>`
so that I could change the tile of the comment area.

Now I want to change the note above the box where guests type their comments. I saw on this site that I can do so by changing
`<?php comment_form(); ?>`
to
`<?php comment_form(array('comment_notes_before' => ‘MY MODIFIED TEXT HERE.’)); ?>`

The problem is, I already changed that bit of code (`<?php comment_form(); ?>`) for my first modification, so it's no longer there. What do I need to do to have both modifications? I've tried different things but no solution yet. I'm new at this, obviously.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is an array, so you can use multiple key-value pairs, like this:

```
comment_form(
    [
        'title_reply'          => 'Leave a comment',
        'comment_notes_before' => 'some text',
    ]
);
```

In your second example you are using curly quotes. These are not valid PHP. Make sure you have the [debug enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) during development, so you can see these errors before you push them to the live site.

Comment: @Claude Please, **never** combine multiple questions in one post. Remove the second question, then try the many solutions we have already for that, and if none of them works (unlikely), then ask a new question. This is not a forum. :)

Comment: Done, but the only reason I asked here is because I've already looked far and wide for the answer and haven't found it. As I said, I'm new to this, so it's hard for me to even know where to look for the answers. And often, said answers are geared at folks with more experience than me, and I am unable to implement them.

Comment: @Claude Search for [`comment_form_default_fields`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=comment_form_default_fields).